# System stops running

Tags: debian, terminal, sleep

I'm using Debian (3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64) as a base to run extremely time consuming calculations. My problem is that, after some time of working (several weeks), and even using a small load of calculations (e.g. 50% of the CPU's) the computer stops working, as if sleeping or hibernating and, at that point I have to reset the system.

I read a lot of discussion regarding disabling of sleeping/hibernating when the screen goes black. But I suspect that this is not my problem. In fact, the computer does not have a screen, keyboard or mouse only an Ethernet connection. Furthermore, I only installed the terminal (no user interface was installed) and ssh to log in to the computer. Thus I have no idea what can be wrong.

Thus anyone have a idea on how I can solve this problem.

P.S. I have this problem in more than one computer. In one of the configurations I'm using PC's with Intel CPUs and ASUS motherboards. In other, I'm using SUPERMICRO servers also with Intel CPUs.

Comment: Have you checked for memory leaks?

Comment: No. How can I do it?

Comment: Well if your time per task is a few weeks start a job up and record current memory usage for its process(s), then ssh back in and check again say 2wks later. If its significantly bigger either the program is designed that way and you need more memory to do X or theres a bug and its leaking memory which should be patched.

Comment: Ok. I will check.